Provide capability to view files like excel, word, ppt in angular application
By Putting original file on a public hosted domain: - we have a library “ngx-doc-viewer” which behind the scenes uses “Google” and “Microsoft” APIs which need a public domain which their server can access, so we can put file on a public server form there it can be accessible, and we can provide the ability to preview the file. Is there any way to view files which are not in public domain as due to security issue we can not keep it's publicly.

You can preview files locally, or you can secure your backend.  (authenticate/authorize requests)
